# How can I use sed to get an xml value

Tags: linux, bash, sed

How can I use sed to get the SOMETHING in `<version.suffix>SOMETHING</version.suffix>`?

I tried `sed 's#.*>\(.*\)\<version\.suffix\>#\1#'` ,but fails.

Comment: I usually try something else if something doesn't work.

Comment: `$ echo '<version.suffix>SOMETHING</version.suffix>'  | xmllint --xpath "/version.suffix/text()" -`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
sed 's/<.*>\(.*\)<.*>/\1/'
```

It should be general enough to get **every** xml value.

If you need to eliminate the indentation add `\s*` at the beginning like this:

```
sed 's/\s*<.*>\(.*\)<.*>/\1/'
```

Alternatively if you **only** want `version.suffix`'s value, you can make the command more specific like this:

```
sed 's/<version\.suffix>\(.*\)<.*>/\1/'
```

Comment: Is it true that the things between "\(" and "\)" will not be replaced?

Comment: Yes. cause putting characters between `\(` and `\)` is practically naming what's inside to refer to later. The first couple is `\1` the second is `\2` etc. And since we referred to `\1` in the 'replace' part, we'll be left with everything inside the `\(` and `\)` marks.

Comment: Then what if I want to replace SOMETHING with other stuff in <version.suffix>SOMETHING</version.suffix>?

Comment: then you can try this: `sed 's/\(<.*>\).*\(<.*>\)/\1SOMETHING NEW\2/'`

Comment: Could you recommend a webpage where I can learn more about how to do this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below sed command,

```
$ echo '<version.suffix>SOMETHING</version.suffix>' | sed 's#^<[^>]*>\(.*\)<\/[^>]*>$#\1#'
SOMETHING
```

- `^<[^>]*>` Matches the first tag string `<version.suffix>`.
- `\(.*\)<\/[^>]*>$` Characters upto the next closing tag are captured. And the remaining closing tag was matched by this `<\/[^>]*>` regex.
- Finally all the matched characters are replaced by the characters which are present inside the group index 1.

Your regex is correct but the only thing is, you forget to use `/` inside the closing tag.

```
$ echo '<version.suffix>SOMETHING</version.suffix>' | sed 's#.*>\(.*\)</version\.suffix>#\1#'
                                                                       |<-Here
SOMETHING
```

Answer (score 1):

Many ways possible, e.g:

with `sed`

```
echo '<version.suffix>SOMETHING</version.suffix>' | sed 's#<[^>]*>##g'
```

or `grep`

```
echo '<version.suffix>SOMETHING</version.suffix>' | grep -oP '<version.suffix>\KSOMETHING(?=</version.suffix>)'
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit why sed 's#<[^>]*>##g' works? Thanks!

Comment: @WeijieWang it search for: 1.opening bracket, 2.any chars what aren't closing bracket 3. closing bracket and substitute to nothing, for all occurences in the line. so remains only the content betwwen.

Comment: I can see now, thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the formatting of the question is accurate, when I run the example in the question as-is:

```
$ echo '<version.suffix>SOMETHING</version.suffix>' | sed 's#.*>\(.*\)\<version\.suffix\>#\1#'
```

I see the following output:

```
SOMETHING</>
```

In case my formatting skills fail me, this output ends with the trailing left angle bracket, a forward slash, and finally the right angle bracket.

So, why this "failure"? Well, on my system (Linux with GNU grep 2.14), `grep(1)` includes the following snippet:

**The Backslash Character and Special Expressions**

**The  symbols  \<  and  \>  respectively  match  the empty string at the beginning and end of a word.**

Other answers suggest good alternatives to extract the value in XML tag syntax; use them.

I just wanted to point out why the RE in the original problem fails on current Linux systems: some symbols match no actual characters, but instead match empty boundaries in these apps that support posix-extended regular expressions. So, in this example, the brackets in the source are matched in unexpected ways:

- the `(.*)`has matched `SOMETHING</`, to be printed by the `\1` back-reference
- the left-hand side of `version.suffix` is matched by `\<`
- `version.suffix` is matched by `version\.suffix`
- the right-hand side of `version.suffix` is matched by `\>`
- the trailing `>` character remains in `sed`'s pattern space and is printed.

TL;DR -`"\X"` does **not** mean "just match an X" for all X!